# How to get selected text value from picker view in IOS Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am not able to get selected text value from picker view (Drop down) in IOS Xamarin.
not in select index changed event.
Thanks Yogesh Kumar

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a class that inherits from UIPickerViewModel and set it on the UIPickerView.

```
_picker.Model = new CustomPickerViewModel();
```

Then in the PickerViewModel you can override the "Selected" method and get the index of the clicked item

```
public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
{
    if (_itemSource != null)
    {
        SelectedItem = _itemSource[(int) row];
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to get whatever value you want from the selected item.